# SQL: Getting the top 5 child records that together are linked in a link table to the same parent table record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

The best way to describe this problem is through an example:

I have 3 tables:

Ingredient:

```
Id     Name
```

Recipe:

```
Id Title NumberOfIngredients
```

RecipeIngredientRelationship:

```
Id RecipeId IngredientId
```

This query:

```
select IngredientId, COUNT(*) cnt 
from RecipeIngredientRelationship rel, Recipe r
where rel.RecipeId = r.Id and r.NumberOfIngredients <= 5
group by IngredientId
order by cnt desc
```

gives me the ingredients in the order of most occurrence for recipes that have 5 or fewer ingredients.

I want to write a query that gives me the top 5 ingredients that together exist in the same recipe.  That is if I want to stock my pantry with only 5 ingredients, then these 5 will allow me to cook the most number of recipes.

Please note that the top 5 rows from the above query is not the right answer since the top 5 ingredients are water, sugar, salt, pepper, oil and there are really no recipes with that however salt, potato, chicken, onion, pepper may be the correct answer.

Comment: Please specify the database you're using. MySQL and SQL-Server both being marked doesn't really help...

Comment: Thanks! I thought of this as a general SQL question and not a db specific one. I fixed it.

Comment: If you are down voting my question please have the courtesy of adding a comment explaining why.

Comment: not a down voter but adding some sample data with desired output would really help, create a sql fiddle

Comment: So, you want the combination of 5 ingredients that must be used on the same recipe that repeats the more across recipes?, that sounds like a hard problem to solve

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter either, but please stop whining for down-voters to explain why they down-voted. [It's not going to happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and is just useless, distracting noise.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify your question:
This will rule out any recipe with more than 5 ingredients since you won't be able to cook a recipe if one ingredient is missing. On the other hand it will include all recipes with less than 5 ingredients.

Furthermore I assume that we could rule out any ingredient that is just used once. Or do you accept a result of a single recipe?

That leads to a variation of all remaining ingredients that needs to be checked against all recipes inclduing the consideration of the recipes with less than 5 ingredients.

Just the simple check with 20 ingredients will lead to 15504 different combinations that needs to be checked against all recipes. To check against 40 ingredients we're talking about more than 650k different combinations....

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph you are correct. Regarding your second paragraph, you are correct if it simplifies the algorithm, ingredients that are only used once among millions of recipes will fall out of the selection at some point or another. Regarding your last point, I do not believe that we need to check all combinations, if the algorithm is clever it will eliminate large groups if a simple condition is satisfied.

Comment: I guess if it's about cooking of the "Western hemisphere" 4 out of those 5 ingredients will be salt, pepper, oil, and onions ;-). The number of theoretical combinations can be reduced by selecting the combinations actually used. But I guess the first two paragraphs mentioned above will rule out quite a large number of recipes. So I'd question the practical useability of the query results...

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 r1id, count(*) from (
    select r.RecipeId r1id, r2.RecipeId r2id from RecipeIngredientRelationship r
    right join RecipeIngredientRelationship r2
    on r2.IngredientId = r.IngredientId
    group by r.RecipeId, r2.RecipeId
    having count(case when r.IngredientId is null then 1 end) = 0
) t1 group by r1id order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A 5x cartesian on ingredients could also be a good solution, because it will create the combinations of ingredients taken 5;
then we can group by the different combinations to obtain the number of occurrences:

```
SELECT I1,I2,I3,I4,I5, COUNT(*) total
FROM (
SELECT 
r1.RecipeId,
r1.IngredientId I1,r2.IngredientId I2,r3.IngredientId I3,r4.IngredientId I4,r5.IngredientId I5
FROM RecipeIngredientRelationship r1
JOIN RecipeIngredientRelationship r2 ON (r1.RecipeId=r2.RecipeId and r1.IngredientId<r2.IngredientId)
JOIN RecipeIngredientRelationship r3 ON (r3.RecipeId=r2.RecipeId and r2.IngredientId<r3.IngredientId)
JOIN RecipeIngredientRelationship r4 ON (r4.RecipeId=r2.RecipeId and r3.IngredientId<r4.IngredientId)
JOIN RecipeIngredientRelationship r5 ON (r5.RecipeId=r2.RecipeId and r4.IngredientId<r5.IngredientId)
) x
GROUP BY  I1,I2,I3,I4,I5
ORDER BY total desc
```